# How to get my app listed in Device Administrators menu in settings on Android 7.1

Tags: android, android-7.1-nougat, device-owner

I am trying to build an app that runs in lock task mode. I want users to go to settings->security->Device Administrators and select my app. But the issue is my app doesn't get listed in Device Administrator menu.
I know that I can set my app as device owner using adb dpm command but its not useful in my scenario.

How can I make my app get listed on Device Administrator.

Comment: Have you checked out the device admin docs? https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin?hl=en

Comment: Yes I have checked the documentation and added the code to my app but it mentions about how do you develop the admin app and ask users to select the app as admin . But the issue with my app is that its not listed under Device Administrators for users to select my app and make it admin

Comment: I think you need to build that functionality into your app. Look at the way the sample app is doing it: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/DeviceAdminSample.java#380